Fun fact+How rare is this?
Primes are of the very important to number theory and number theory has a large application public-key cryptography and computer science, how odd is this, that in this time there is not even one prime "Total reputation" in Crypto SE.


i think before this can be answered you should state what your assumptions are about the distribution of rep

I'm not really sure what you mean – the number of users with 100,000 or more reputation is 2, which is a prime. An odd one, since it is even, but a prime nonetheless. The left column contains numbers (actually, intervals) which largely match privilege levels and those use 'nice' round decimal numbers since Stack Exchange users are familiar with them from daily life.
If you're interested in the distribution of reputation, you should use the Stack Exchange Data Explorer, which I did e.g. here for Stack Overflow. The disadvantages are:

you're always looking at a snapshot from last Sunday morning
SQL Server doesn't have a built-in function for primes

This is how the reputation distribution on Cryptography Stack Exchange looks like (when viewed on a log-log scale):


Thank you for your good answer, I have my answer and you provided even more detail.
